# How to echo the result from an object without also returning the type in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

Database Structure:

```
internal_id | transaction_id | transaction_value | user_id
```

PHP Code:

```
public static function getBalance() {

    $userId = Session::get('user_id');

    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT SUM(transaction_value) as sum
              FROM transactions_received
             WHERE user_id = (:user_id) LIMIT 1";
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':user_id' => $userId));

    $result = $query->fetch()->sum;

    $balance = !empty($result)? $result: null;

    if($balance==null) {
        $balanceZero = "0";
        return $balanceZero;
    } else {
        return $balance;
    }

}
```

Standalone `$query->fetch();` Output:

```
 object(stdClass)#7 (1) { ["sum"]=> string(10) "0.00449300" }
```

`$query->fetch()->sum;` Output:

```
string(10) "0.00449300"
```

The problem:

I am trying to only return `0.00449300` without the type included. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `print_r` or `var_dump` to print that to the screen?

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan Real facepalm moment there... Was using var_dump instead of print_r... it works now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was initially outputting the response via `var_dump` instead of `print_r`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).